# In Android Socket Programming, server side gives errors:

Tags: android, sockets, networking

I am trying to implement an Android Socket Programming program for a project but the code seems to be giving two errors. Trying my best to solve them but any help will be highly appreciated, thanks. The code is given below with the errors "Public type server must be defined in it's own file" and "R cannot be resolve as a variable" being bolded:

```
package com.example.androidsocketserver;



import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.widget.TextView;
**public class Server extends Activity** {

    private ServerSocket serverSocket;

    Handler updateConversationHandler;

    Thread serverThread = null;

    private TextView text;

    public static final int SERVERPORT = 6000;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        **setContentView(R.layout.main);**

        **text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text2);**

        updateConversationHandler = new Handler();

        this.serverThread = new Thread(new ServerThread());
        this.serverThread.start();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        try {
            serverSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    class ServerThread implements Runnable {

        public void run() {
            Socket socket = null;
            try {
                serverSocket = new ServerSocket(SERVERPORT);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {

                try {

                    socket = serverSocket.accept();

                    CommunicationThread commThread = new CommunicationThread(socket);
                    new Thread(commThread).start();

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    class CommunicationThread implements Runnable {

        private Socket clientSocket;

        private BufferedReader input;

        public CommunicationThread(Socket clientSocket) {

            this.clientSocket = clientSocket;

            try {

                this.input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.clientSocket.getInputStream()));

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public void run() {

            while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {

                try {

                    String read = input.readLine();

                    updateConversationHandler.post(new updateUIThread(read));

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

    }

    class updateUIThread implements Runnable {
        private String msg;

        public updateUIThread(String str) {
            this.msg = str;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            text.setText(text.getText().toString()+"Client Says: "+ msg + "\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is server the only public class in your file. If you have define other activity in the same file then you need to create new file call server and put the server activity in that file.

Comment: Thanks. Changed the MainActivity.java file to Server.java and it worked. Could you tell me how to fix the "R cannot be resolve as a variable" error?

Comment: Try cleaning you project. If error is still there check xml files to see if there are any errors